# A bit of feedback regarding whether my questions are considered good or bad

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

If I ask a question;

- Will I get an answer?
- Will I get many answers?
- Will I get ignored (no answers, no comments, no votes)?
- Will the question appear among Hot Network Questions?
- Will it get a ton of upvotes?
- Will it be severly downvoted?
- Will it be closed?
- Will it be deleted?

Honestly, I stopped trying to predict. When I have a question, I try to word it so that it'd be acceptable on a site and ask it. I've experienced all of the aforementioned outcomes already, but what will happen after I click the Post Your Question button, is a dice roll for me. Too many times I though a question would be a good one, only to see it downvoted and closed. Too many times I was asking a question, thinking "oops, I fear they're not going to like it, but I need the answer so badly, I'll just give it a try, maybe someone answers me before it is closed, a couple of downvotes now won't likely get me questionbanned", only to see the question highly upvoted, and maybe even among the Hot Network Questions.

I used to try to argue for some closed questions in the meta and / or asking what did people not like in them. I stopped doing this as well, mainly because it's too time and energy consuming (and unlikely to get me an answer). Also because I've noticed that, over the Internet and real life alike, people tend to really get annoyed when I try to argue, and I wouldn't like to get a notorious reputation here. (Although, to be honest, not all meta posts of mine we're getting me such a feedback).

I just thought a bit of feedback would be OK, sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Or is the FAQ too general?

Comment: What's your actual question here?

Comment: If it doesn't work here, or simply doesn't get admitted, then try it somewhere else.  If you care enough about it to work with it, then I'd recommend talking to the people who actually closed your question:  meta is always available, and for you so is chat.  I did that on a few sites, and only one of them did I not get satisfactory responses.  Pardon me if you've heard all this already.

Comment: Sometimes what is an otherwise well written and lucid composition can be shot down because it fails one point against the rules held for a site — and, sometimes they don't.  People aren't always consistent.

Answer (score 4):

In your question here you give no indication as to whether you have taken the site's Tour and started to review the site's Help Center, particularly its On Topic and How To Ask pages, before starting to ask questions on it.

I can understand how someone not doing those things, perhaps having come from discussion forums or other Q&A sites, might be bewildered as to why these focused Q&A sites do not work the way that they are used to.

I am sometimes surprised when a question of mine is initially poorly received, but on every occasion, a few more re-reads of my question, and reading and thinking about the votes and comments that I do receive on it, leads me to improving it via edits.  The reputation of that question then usually resurrects.

Comment: I can confirm that.